# Copy files from one folder to another and rename the files

Tags: python, file, copy, shutil

I want to copy a huge number of .html-files to another folder. Additionally, I want to change the name of the file to "FoldersName_Filename".

```
import shutil
    import os
    for Jahr in range(2000,2014):
        for Datei in os.listdir("S:\\DA\\html\\Jahrescluster\\%i" %Jahr):
            shutil.copy2(src="S:\\html\\Jahrescluster\\%i\\%s" % (Jahr, Datei), dst="S:\\html\\2000-2013\\%i_%s" (Jahr, Datei))
```

The code produces the following error:

```
shutil.copy2(src="S:\\html\\Jahrescluster\\%i\\%s" % (Jahr, Datei), dst="S:\\html\\2000-2013\\%i_%s" (Jahr, Datei))

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
import shutil
import os

for Jahr in range(2000,2014):
    for Datei in os.listdir("S:\\DA\\html\\Jahrescluster\\%i" %Jahr):
        shutil.copy2(src="S:\\html\\Jahrescluster\\{}\\{}".format(Jahr, Datei), dst="S:\\html\\2000-2013\\{}_{}".format(Jahr, Datei))
```